# PXDBCalced - how to invoke

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom DAC in which I have an unbound field on which I've applied a PXDBCalced attribute.  I used PXDBCalced because I'm using two other fields that are on the DAC row.  Here's how I have the field defined:

```
    public abstract class margin : PX.Data.IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXDecimal(2)]
[PXDBCalced(typeof(Sub<IsNull<CFSVCProfile.revenueBudget,CFHelper.decimal_0>, 
CFSVCProfile.costBudget>), typeof(Decimal))]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Margin", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual decimal? Margin { get; set; }
```

The problem I am having is that the field that has the PXDBCalced attribute is not getting updated when I update the row in the DAC.  So, how do I get the calculation to run and update the field?

Thanks!

Comment: If the same table you could use PXUnboundDefault vs PXDBCalced

Comment: Yep, it's the same table.  Let me try that.

Comment: Sorry not sure what i was thinking, PXFormula or PXUnboundFormula is what you can use (not PXUnboundDefault)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try PXFormula or PXUnboundFormula on your field as its not necessary to hit the database with PXDBCalced based on your example.

```
[PXUnboundFormula(typeof(Sub<IsNull<CFSVCProfile.revenueBudget,CFHelper.decimal_0>, 
    CFSVCProfile.costBudget>))]
```

Comment: Both might work initially, but if pulling the field into reports, GI, or other pages you might need PXUnboundFormula to get the field to calculate when the row is selected because it is an unbound field. If it was a bound field then PXFormula would be all you need. Glad this worked anyhow.